# Order list in jsp using name attribute

Tags: jquery, jsp

I'm trying to order a list by the attribute "name".
I understand [how order a list by its value](https://jsfiddle.net/sappe/qapatdfn/4/), but I don't get what should I write instead of

```
$(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
```

I've tryed

```
$(a).att('name').toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).att('name').toUpperCase());
```

but it doesn't work.
Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
$(a).find('a').attr('name').localeCompare($(b).find('a').attr('name'));
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qapatdfn/5/